# Bluetooth HM-10 in central mode bonding with another bluetooth device

Tags: bluetooth, hm-10

I have a bluetooth HM-10 configured in central mode. I have successfully connected it to another bluetooth device (a hexiwear bluetooth wearable). The problem now is that the hexiwear requires me to provide a 6 digit pin before it will bond with my HM-10.

Would anyone know the AT command that I could use to send the 6 digit pin from the HM-10 to the hexiwear?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Default code of HM 10 is 000000 , you can change it with At+PASS{new_pin} command. However if you match the two pins (the HM10 pin and the hexiwear pin) the devices will connect together!  So put 000000 in your peripheral device (hexiwear). Else, if you can't put the pin in the  hexiwear, change the default pin on the HM10.